# How can I specify which location type address to use for a proximity search

Tags: custom-search, location-type

I collect both home and work address data for contacts. I assume - although I've not yet tested it - that the default location type is used when a proximity search is carried out.

I have work address set as my default, but want to do a proximity search based on home address.

Anyone know if this can be done, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Drupal you can do this via views (where you have full control over which field types you pull in).

Here's a good example:
[Views Proximity Search on Latitude / Longitude](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/224/views-proximity-search-on-latitude-longitude)

Comment: Many thanks for this - most helpful. Any takers from a Wordpress perspective?